# Custom Datetime validation not working in Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, lombok

I have created a custom date Validator for checking the timestamp string like as shown below. The code is working fine, but validation is not working and no message is showing in the response body.

When I post as data like as shown below

```
{
  "price": "0",
  "timestamp": "foo foo"
}
```

it is giving me 200. My exception is to get the valid exception details.  Can anyone please help me on this

**StockController.java**

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/stock", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class StockController {

    @Autowired
    private StockService stockService;

    @PostMapping
    public void createStock(@Valid @RequestBody final Stock stock) {
        stockService.create(stock);
    }
}
```

**DefaultControllerAdvice.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public Exception handleException(Exception exception){
        return exception;
    }
}
```

**Stock.java**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import com.challenge.validators.TimestampValidator;

import lombok.Data;

    @Data
    public class Stock {

        @Min(0)
        @NotNull
        public double price;

        @NotNull(message="Timestamp cannot be empty")
        @DateTimeValidator
        public String timestamp;
    }
```

**DateTimeValidator.java**

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateTimeValidatorCheck.class)
@Documented
public @interface DateTimeValidator {

    String message() default "Must be timestamp of format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**DateTimeValidatorCheck.java**

```
public class DateTimeValidatorCheck implements ConstraintValidator<DateTimeValidator, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(DateTimeValidator dateTimeValidator ) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String timestamp, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (timestamp == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                LocalDate.parse(timestamp, dateTimeFormatter);
                return true;
            } catch (DateTimeParseException dateTimeParseException) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is none of the validation annotations checked, or just not your custom validator?

Comment: @JanRieke no....even if I takes of `timestamp` from request body it is not validating and giving me 200

Answer (score 0):

You need a `BindingResult bindingResult` parameter on your `createStock` method. Use this to check for validation errors:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    // return error or throw exception
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.....but we cant use any logic in our controller which is the customer requirement

Comment: The validation logic is still in the custom validator. The controller just has to check if there are errors.